# Union type doesn't work with object literal

Tags: flowtype

Please see flowtry below. Line 17 is a union between a union type and an object literal. When I use the type on line 36, it tells me it can't find the properties of the type within the union.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
type NativeMockPlayerSourceConfig = {}

type BitmovinPlayerSourceConfig =
  | BitmovinPlayerSourceConfigHLS
  | BitmovinPlayerSourceConfigDash

type BitmovinPlayerSourceConfigHLS = {
  tag: 'HLS',
  hls: string,
}

type BitmovinPlayerSourceConfigDash = {
  tag: 'DASH',
  dash: string,
}

type LiveSourceConfig = BitmovinPlayerSourceConfig | NativeMockPlayerSourceConfig

interface NativePlayer {
  +load: LiveSourceConfig => Promise<void>,
}

type NativeBitmovinPlayer = {
  load: BitmovinPlayerSourceConfig => Promise<NativeBitmovinPlayer>,
}

type PromisePassthrough<C: any> = any => Promise<C>

type NativeMockPlayer = {
  load: PromisePassthrough<NativeMockPlayer>,
}

class BitmovinPlayer implements NativePlayer {
  ref: NativeBitmovinPlayer

  async load(source: BitmovinPlayerSourceConfig) {
    await this.ref.load(source)
  }
}

class MockPlayer implements NativePlayer {
  ref: NativeMockPlayer

  async load(config: NativeMockPlayerSourceConfig) {
    this.ref.load(config)
  }
}
```

Thank you

[flowtry](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAcghsAlgNwgWQPYGMDWAFAGzhAgCcBlDAV1KwgGEMA7AM0QHMoBeKAbwF8AUINCQoAIUTAAthmSImhYmUo06jVh26CoUAD4Sps+YqIkK1Wg2Zt2ACQAy5HfsMy5CpedVWNtgCJwAM4AFsKi0JLuJl4qluo2HI7k3HwuwHDsAFxQAOTJuQA0LiEEQTlBwKQK7MVCIuCRRh6myhZq1prsgaGpvOmZObn+AILkdkUuACbBIRVVNXXhjVAOKBA+CV2pUcaeZnEdfloG8EiomLix7b6J7MIKwGQscHSwCOvXaboA1AQYcCmOTWqE2nVs3AAfFA8KQMNJEEEIAAeZAYRBTSFLBpiM7rXYtL48fq6f6AnIEmIHG5bCFcaGw+GIlF41CU-ZtLGCeoRGFwhFIvDBSohOFUdghZH0HJwJggaE8WUgKF8plIqWQlw46Cs9DYfDUvouMlA1UCiBCoIisUS5G6y4GznYrBEK1uPatcxQRDSMAECDSCBMYBBd7nC2GklQUgQFg5XXsz1kYS6YIgJhYKAmgAUQXiEApzSpbTBx3YAEpvrooHAAO5wKRQYAhREAOhjLFbObzHXLLiE9RdwqgDq+Pr9AaDIbDn0jLg78Y+F311xTNaC6czOawd0X4dH1NLd0rUd0zbbHa7AKm2Z3XT7ugHgiAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way but this works:

[flowtry](https://flow.org/try/#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-q6UgQFg5C3C0NkYS6YIgJhYKD2hFBeIQFnNNltYHHdgY9O6KBwADucCkUFd+IAdJmWP2K1WOmiXEJ6v75VBvfSI1GY3GEx9zhAU2mXEOc58LlbroX20ES2WK8iurv1-P2Y27i2XLo+0FB1mR7Cpkj75PxYIgA)